# rman : how to only restore a tablespace (without recovering)?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-backups, database-restore, rman

I have 2 tablespaces which I want to backup when they are in a consistent state (let's say T0). When problems occur (T1), I want to be able to restore both tablespaces to their state at T0 **without recovering all changes that occured between T0 and T1** (I want to ignore them all).
What I could do so far is backing up and recovering tablespaces (with changes that occured after the backup, which is not what I want).
I am using Oracle 11gR2 XE and RMAN.
I am looking for a solution compatible with Oracle 10 g and above.
Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: how is T0 defined?  Is it a particular time?  Or the state before a recurrent operation?  Or some arbitrary moment in the life of your database?  Is this an ongoing requirement or a one-off?

Comment: T0 is the time I backup the DB before launching an operation which I am not sure it will succed. To be more clear, I have an automated process which transform a class diagram into SQL queries and then execute those generated queries. Those queries should be executed within a transaction : either they succed or are cancelled. The problem is that some of the queries are of type DDL which autocommit in oracle. I want to backup my tablespaces, then launch the queries, and if they fail I will have to cancel all changes (DDLs) by restoring the backup (the restoring should be automated too).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that is transportable tablespace (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/transportable-tablespaces.php).
You'll transport your tablespace in an empty database before your operation.
After you have to do a full backup on your new database.
If a problem occur during your migration you could do the inverse operation.

Of course, test this solution before!

Comment: I've just read the demo you posted. This solution doesn't suit my case because It needs a second database which is not always possible to have nor the time to configure it.

Comment: It's very easy to create an empty database. You could find many scripts on internet and after it will be easy to do.

Comment: you are right but I want to minimise the required configuration. it's not a problem in the test enviromnent but I am thinking about the production enviromnent.

Answer (score 0):

What about TABLESPACE POINT IN TIME recovery? Would it suit your needs?

PS: It has some prerequisites like NO FKs into tables in other tablespaces.
And maybe it is not allowed in XE releases.

Comment: It's not supported in XE releases (as you said) thus I can't use it.